# Understanding movement's direction by comparing 2 pictures

Tags: image-processing, gps, feature-extraction, opticalflow, sensor-fusion

I need to detect the direction of the phone's movement by comparing some pictures taken sequentially by the camera of this phone. Is OpenCV my best option? Could GPS be helpful? Could accelerometer or gyroscope be helpful? I know the theory behind, more or less, I am asking in hope to get an answer from somebody who has a **real hands-on experience**.

Comment: sounds like Augmented Reality